AppVeyor build passing on build page, but shows a failing X and saying "AppVeyor build failed" on github
Here's just a few examples of the AppVeyor build looking like it passed without producing any errors
https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ccxt/ccxt/builds/49677831
https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ccxt/ccxt/builds/49676345
https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ccxt/ccxt/builds/49688976
https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ccxt/ccxt/builds/49689375
but yet there's a failing red X on the github PR and saying "AppVeyor build failed"
I have no idea what could be causing the failed builds

